# How to pass list to Python worker thread?

Tags: python

How to pass a list to Python `threading.Thread`?
In the beflow example, I am converting the list to a dictionary. Is there a way to pass list as such to `doWork` method?

```
def launcher():
    #.... 
   list = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3','name4']
   nameList = { 'names' : list }
   workThread = threading.Thread(target=self.doWork, kwargs=nameList)
   workThread.start()

def doWork(self, **kwargs):
    for i, name in enumerate(kwargs['nameList']):
        print i, name
```

Comment: you are taking `**kwargs` as parameter which accepts a mapping of key value pairs, If you could change it to `*args` then you could probably pass list instead of a dictionary

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to pass in `list` by encapsulating it in a tuple. That way, when I use *args, it won't try to unpack.

```
workThread = threading.Thread(target=self.doWork, args=(list,))

def doWork(self, *args):
    for i, name in enumerate(args[0]]):
        print i, name
```

Answer (score 13):

The reason being that `workThread = threading.Thread(target=doWork, args=lst)` takes the second argument as a list and then maps the contents of the `lst` to the various arguments required by the method or function, Now since you want to pass only a single argument to the function which is a list, So if you see the common Syntax it is written some thing like: `args = (param1, param2,...)`

Now since you have only 1 argument so this reduces to `args = (param1)` Now replacing the param1 with a list you will get `args = ([1, 2, 3...])`, So actually the point here is that you need a nested list to pass as `args` because the arguments are enclosed inside the list or a tuple so you need to wrap your `list` inside a list or tuple. Any content under that wrapper list would be mapped with the arguments of the function or method being called.

To make the scenario clear:

> If you pass args = [1, 2, 3, 4] then you mean that you are passing
>   these 4 values as the arguments to that function or method.
>
> On the other side if you pass `args = [[1, 2, 3, 4]]` or `args = ([1,
>   2, 3, 4], )` or `args = ((1, 2, 3, 4), )` Then **only** the whole list
>   or tuple would be passed as a parameter to the function or method
>   called.

I have simplified your code snippet to look like :

```
import threading

lst = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3','name4', "a"]

def doWork(param):
    for i, name in enumerate(param):
        print i, name

workThread = threading.Thread(target=doWork, args=(lst,))
workThread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's correct except you sent in the list with keyword = "names" but you are trying to access it as "nameList" in your worker